# Sub-martingale and a.s convergence

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

I was reading lecture on martingale where the following result is proved. Unfortunately it's not very detailed.

I appreciate if you could explain why $Y_\infty^{(p)}$ are equal $\mathbb{P}$-a.s, from the fact $Q_{p+1}\subset Q_p$ and how to conclude from the right continuity that $X_r \to Y_{\infty} \ \mathbb{P}$-a.s.

Update: perhaps the a.s equality is true because, $Y_{k}^{(p)}=Y_{2k}^{(p+1)},$ the limit is unique a.s so $Y_{\infty}^{(p)}=Y_{\infty}^{(p+1)},$ for all $p \geq 1$, so $Q_p$ are not necessary.
[image: 2]

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It's best if questions remain self-contained and not include links to other pages. See: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10992/671710

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reason for why $Y^{(p)}_\infty = Y^{(p+1)}_\infty$ is correct, but I'm not sure I agree with the statement that "$Q_p$ are not necessary."  The reason we have $Y_{2k}^{(p+1)} = Y_{k}^{(p)}$ is because of the fact that $Q_{p+1} \subset Q_p$, so it is necessary we use something like $Q_p$ here.

Now to conclude $X_r \rightarrow Y_\infty$, note that by right-continuity of $X$ we have $$\limsup_{r \rightarrow \infty} X_r = \limsup_{r \rightarrow \infty, r \in Q} X_r$$ where $Q := \bigcup_{p \in \mathbb{N}} Q_p$ and similarly $$\liminf_{r \rightarrow \infty} X_r = \liminf_{r \rightarrow \infty, r \in Q} X_r.$$

However, because $Y_k^{(p)} \rightarrow Y_\infty$ a.s., we know $\limsup_{r \rightarrow \infty, r \in Q} X_r = Y_\infty$ and $\liminf_{r \rightarrow \infty, r \in Q} X_r = Y_\infty$ a.s.  Since $$\limsup_{r \rightarrow \infty} X_r = \liminf_{r \rightarrow \infty} X_r = Y_\infty$$
we conclude $\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} X_r = Y_\infty$.

EDIT: After thinking about this more carefully, I don't think this is correct, and I don't think the proof presented in the original question works either for the same reason.  This doesn't use the fact that $X$ is a sub-martingale except to conclude each $Y_k^{(p)}$ converges, but we could make a right-continuous process that doesn't converge, and still has the property that each $Y_k^{(p)}$ converges.  For example, the process that is $1$ on intervals of the form $[n+2^{-n},n+2^{1-n})$ and $0$ everywhere else, i.e. \begin{align*}
X_r := \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1_{[n+2^{-n},n+2^{1-n})}(r),
\end{align*} has the property that each $Y_k^{(p)}$ is eventually constant at $0$, but $\limsup_{r \rightarrow \infty} X_r = 1$.

The typical way I've seen this proof is to look at downcrossings and use the downcrossing inequality, e.g. Section 2.2 in *Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion* by Revuz and Yor.  Here's a sketch of that proof:

For a countable subset $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $a < b$, let $D(a,b,E)$ be the number of downcrossings of the interval $(a,b)$ by $X|_E$ ($X$ restricted to $E$).  The discrete time downcrossing inequality tells us $D(a,b,E)$ is finite almost surely for all countable $E$, so by choosing $E$ to be a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and using right-continuity we conclude that $X$ can only have finitely many downcrossings in any interval $(a,b)$.  This implies $\liminf_{r \rightarrow \infty} X_r = \limsup_{r \rightarrow \infty} X_r$ because if $\liminf_{r \rightarrow \infty} X_r < \limsup_{r \rightarrow \infty} X_r$ then there must exist $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\liminf_{r \rightarrow \infty} X_r < a < b < \limsup_{r \rightarrow \infty} X_r$, but that implies $X_r$ has infinitely many downcrossings in the interval $(a,b)$ and therefore $P(\liminf_{r \rightarrow \infty} X_r < \limsup_{r \rightarrow \infty} X_r) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! One request: the sequence $(X_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}=(Y_k^{(0)})_{r \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges a.s to a r.v $X$, so $P(\{(X_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \ \text{converges to} \ X\})=1,$ on the other hand, $P(\bigcap_{p \in \mathbb{N}}\{ (X_{\frac{k}{2^p}})_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \ \text{converges}\})=1,$ leading to $P(K)=1,(K=\{(X_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \ \text{converges to} \ X\} \cap \bigcap_{p \in \mathbb{N}}\{ (X_{\frac{k}{2^p}})_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \ \text{converges}\})$

Comment: Can we use this facts, the completness of $\mathbb{R}$ to prove that, on $K,$ $X_r \to X$ $P$-a.s, using the definition $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0,\forall r \geq \delta,|X_r(w)-X(w)| \leq \epsilon$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right.

Comment: you wrote that $Y_k^{(p)} \to Y_{\infty}$ implies $\limsup_{r \to \infty,r \in Q}X_r=Y_{\infty}=\liminf_{r \to \infty,r \in Q}X_r \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1).$ why is this true? Are you using that if for all $p,Y_k^{(p)}$ then $(1)$ is true? Why is this true ? (It looks you're using that if for all $p,Y_k^{(p)}$ converges to $Y_{\infty}$ then $Y_{k}^{(k)}$ converges to $Y_{\infty}$)

Comment: I confess it's not clear

Comment: Indeed, there was a mistake in what I had originally.  I added an edit explaining it and sketching a different proof.